# textbox ошибка наложения типов (sql query)

Tags: c#, sql, windows, textbox

Выдает эту ошибку

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' to type
>   'System.IConvertible'.'

на мой запрос

```
shoeseTableAdapter.Insert(idshoes, textBox_madein.Text, textBox_material.Text, textBox_size.Text, Convert.ToInt32(textBox_quantity.Text),sex, Convert.ToByte(s2[0]), Convert.ToInt32(textBox_price.Text), textBox_model.Text);
```

Что не так с тексбоксами ?

Comment: s2[0] - это что?

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы разобраться, где возникает ошибка в этом коде:

```
shoeseTableAdapter.Insert(
    idshoes, 
    textBox_madein.Text, 
    textBox_material.Text, 
    textBox_size.Text, 
    Convert.ToInt32(textBox_quantity.Text),
    sex, 
    Convert.ToByte(s2[0]), 
    Convert.ToInt32(textBox_price.Text), 
    textBox_model.Text);
```

Я бы предложил сделать следующее: вынести передаваемые параметы, которые вы конвертируете при передаче, в отдельные переменные, чтобы удостовериться, что там все работает хорошо. Но и это еще не все, удостоверьтесь, что вы передаете правильные типы данных в метод.

```
var quantity = Convert.ToInt32(textBox_quantity.Text);
var sTwo = Convert.ToByte(s2[0]); // предполагаемое место ошибки
var price = Convert.ToInt32(textBox_price.Text);

// если до метода ваш код отработал исправно, проверяйте типы данных
shoeseTableAdapter.Insert(
    idshoes, // проверьте тип данных
    textBox_madein.Text, // строка (string)
    textBox_material.Text, // строка (string)
    textBox_size.Text, // строка (string)
    quantity, // целое число (int)
    sex, // проверьте тип данных
    sTwo, // байт (byte)
    price, // целое число (int)
    textBox_model.Text); // строка (string)
```

Конечно, нужно поставить точку останова и в отладке посмотреть, что у вас хранится в той или иной переменной. Есть предположение, что ошибка кроется в явном преобразовании `Convert.ToByte(s2[0])`, если нет, то ищите проблему в неявном преобразовании, где возможны ошибки с типом (это места, где я написал *"проверьте тип данных"*).

Места, с точно такой же ошибкой:

- [Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' to type 'System.IConvertible'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26705825/5275890)
- [Unable to cast object of type 'system.windows.forms.textbox' to type 'System.IConvertible' error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29040850/5275890)
- [Unable to cast object of type 'system.windows.forms.textbox' to type 'System.IConvertible' error for c# form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46437200/5275890)

Как вы можете заметить, вопрос достаточно популярный, но по своей сути лишь является следствием невнимательности во время написания кода.

И крайний совет, относительно преобразования данных, я бы рекомендовал использовать вместо метода `Convert.ToInt32` местод [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) (а также метод [`Byte.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.byte.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)), лишь по причине того, что метод не упадет с исключением, если не удалось преобразование.

> Метод [`Int32.TryParse (String, Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) - преобразует строковое
>   представление числа в эквивалентное ему 32-битовое целое число со
>   знаком. Возвращает значение, указывающее, успешно ли выполнено
>   преобразование.